# How to store multiple data (array) to a method from Scanner?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I'm trying to get multiple data from user using a `Scanner` for subject details. For example: user inputs number 3 then user has to input subject name, subject code and subject fee 3 times and I want the details to be stored in an array and last to be displayed.

**EDIT:** 
Thanks to @Ksap the code runs fine but the small issue is the first values entered is not displayed(null) only last input is displayed.
screenshot: [image]

so far this is subject class:

```
public class Subject {
public String[] subjectName;
public String[] subjectCode;
public Double[] subjectFee;

  //default constructor 
  Subject(){            
    }

 Subject(String[] subjectCode, String[] subjectName, Double[] subjectFee){
     this.subjectCode = subjectCode; 
     this.subjectName = subjectName;
     this.subjectFee = subjectFee;
   }
    //**********************************Setter Methods******************************\\
public void setSubjectCode(String[] subjectCode){
     this.subjectCode=subjectCode;
}
public void setSubjectName(String[] subjectName){
     this.subjectName=subjectName;
}
public void setSubjectFee(Double[] subjectFee){ 
     this.subjectFee=subjectFee;
}
//**********************************Getter Methods******************************\\

public String[] getSubjectCode(){ 
       return subjectCode;
}
public String[] getSubjectName(){
       return subjectName;
}
public double[] getSubjectFee(){ 
       return subjectFee;
}
}
```

and the SubjectDriver:

```
public class SubjectDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int subjectAmount;
    Subject a = new Subject();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out
        .println("Please input the amount of subjects are you resposible  for ?( Maximum 4)");
    subjectAmount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

    a.subjectName = new String[subjectAmount];
    a.subjectCode = new String[subjectAmount];
    a.subjectFee = new Double[subjectAmount];

    for (int index = 0; index < subjectAmount; index++) {
        System.out.println("enter subject name: ");
        a.subjectName[index] = input.nextLine();;

        System.out.println("enter subject code: ");
        a.subjectCode[index] = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter subject fee: ");
        a.subjectFee[index] = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println("Subject name: " + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectName())
        + "\nSubject Code: " + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectCode()) + "\nSubject fee: "
        + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectFee()));
}
```

}

your help will be much appreciable

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Comment: instead of using arrays why don't you use `ArrayList`

Comment: What is your problem here..?

Comment: this error:     
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at practiveArray.SubjectDriver.main(SubjectDriver.java:20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you got `Nullpointerexception` because of uninitialized arrays, to solve that add these lines on top of the `for loop`

```
a.subjectName = new String[subjectAmount];
a.subjectCode = new String[subjectAmount];
a.subjectFee = new double[subjectAmount];
```

and looks like your `Scanner` also won't work as expected because of mix use of `nextInt` and `nextLine`, to solve this

replace `subjectAmount=input.nextInt();` by this `subjectAmount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine())` and
`a.subjectFee[index]=input.nextDouble()` by this `a.subjectFee[index] = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());`

**Edit:**
When printing the `array` it will print the reference of the `array`, if we want to view the content of the array convert it as List and print it like this
`Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectName())`
so the `print` statement will look like this

```
System.out.println("Subject name: " + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectName())
            + "\nSubject Code: " + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectCode()) + "\nSubject fee: "
            + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectFee()));
```

for your information, `subjectFee` is the `primitive double` array so it will still print the reference, to view the value, declare it as `Double` array.

```
public class SubjectDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int subjectAmount;
        Subject a = new Subject();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
            .println("Please input the amount of subjects are you resposible  for ?( Maximum 4)");
        subjectAmount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

        a.subjectName = new String[subjectAmount];
        a.subjectCode = new String[subjectAmount];
        a.subjectFee = new Double[subjectAmount];

        for (int index = 0; index < subjectAmount; index++) {
            System.out.println("enter subject name: ");
            a.subjectName[index] = input.nextLine();;

            System.out.println("enter subject code: ");
            a.subjectCode[index] = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("enter subject fee: ");
            a.subjectFee[index] = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
        }

        System.out.println("Subject name: " + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectName())
            + "\nSubject Code: " + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectCode()) + "\nSubject fee: "
            + Arrays.asList(a.getSubjectFee()));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much :)  it works somewhat but it does not display the System.out.println() probably, do you know ?

Comment: so far this is the: Subject name: 
[null, null, null, python]
 Subject Code: 
[null, null, null, c444]
 Subject fee: 
[[D@5c647e05]

Comment: i mean why it doesnt show all the inputs ? it only shows the last input

Comment: @OTAMD can i know the input values you entered

Comment: my input was as follow: Please input the amount of subjects are you resposible for ?( Maximum 4)

2
enter subject name: 
java
enter subject code: 
c222
enter subject fee: 
1200
enter subject name: 
php
enter subject code: 
c444
enter subject fee: 
1200
Subject name: [null, php]
Subject Code: [null, c444]
Subject fee: [[D@5c647e05]
 ...... the first input was displayed as null !

Comment: @OTAMD i'll post the `SubjectDriver` class check it with your one

Comment: pleas see the photo there's null value,the first input is not displayed: http://i59.tinypic.com/11v5snn.png

Comment: Edit your question with current `SubjectDriver` and `Subject` classes. i`ll check

Comment: Code working fine, problem should be somewhere else, i used jdk7